# May I know how to add select onchange in dynamic field

Tags: javascript

I had added the select onchange like this but it turns out grey for the rest of the coding....What I need is that whenever i choose an item the price will automatically change..anyone can help me with this? Much appreciated!!

```
<select onChange="$('#output').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('price'))" name="name[]" id="conname" class="form-control" required>
<?php
    
    echo $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblitem WHERE STATUS = 'A'";
    $Result = mysqli_query($Link,$SQL);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($Result) > 0)

    {
        echo "<option></option>";
        for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($Result);$i++)

        {
            $Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);

            echo "<option price=\"".$Row['sellingPrice']."\" value=\"".$Row['itemID']."\"";
            echo">".$Row['itemID']." ".$Row['itemName']."</option>";

        }

}

?>
```

This is the dynamic field code....

$('#dynamic_field').append(' <td padding-right: 10px; style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;"><td  padding-right: 10px; style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">X');

```
    for(j=0;j<values.length;j++){

        

         $('#txtConname'+i).append('<option value="'+storeId[j]+'">'+values[j]+'</option>');

    }

    

});
```

Comment: Post actual code, not an image.

Comment: ^^ Not to mention, this looks like `HTML` and `JavaScript` ..  Not `PHP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few things wrong with your code. So I'll answer your question directly. Remove the `onchange` attribute on your first `<select>`, and before the `</body>` tag (or at the very bottom of your page), add the below code. I added comments to help you understand what is happening.

```js
<script>
// creates an on-change listener for the select element with id of conname
document.querySelector('#conname').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  // gets the index of the currently selected option
  var selected_index = event.target.selectedIndex;
  // get the price value from the currently selected option
  var price = event.target.options[selected_index].getAttribute('price') || '';
  // alerts the price to the user
  window.alert(price + ' was selected.');
});
</script>
```

Edit: I also realized you were using jQuery after I created this code. But code above will still work for you.

Comment: It works for the first attemp, but when i clicked on "add more" for the dynamic field, it doesnt work for the next one.......

Comment: There is no “add more” field in your code. I’m working with what you posted.